# Elixir & Phoenix: add memcache_client library to app

Tags: memcached, elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to use this libary in my Phoenix App to connect to Memcache: https://github.com/tsharju/memcache_client

When I run my server I get this error:

```
** (exit) exited in: :gen_server.call(Memcache.Client.Pool, {:checkout, #Reference<0.0.1.768>, true}, 5000)
    ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its application isn't started
              :erlang.send(Memcache.Client.Pool, {:"$gen_cast", {:cancel_waiting, #Reference<0.0.1.768>}}, [:noconnect])
```

I know there is a doc saying:

> Also, remember to add :memcache_client to your :applications list if
>   you wish that the application is started automatically.

But I don't understand what I should do in my Phoenix app. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `mix.exs`, add `:memcache_client` to the key `:applications` in the function `application/0`:

```
def application do
  [mod: {MyApp, []},
   applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                  :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex]]
end
```

->

```
def application do
  [mod: {MyApp, []},
   applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                  :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :memcache_client]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Just edit the mix.exs file. There is a method application that returns applications list:

```
def application do
[mod: {MyApp, []},
 applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex, :memcache_client]] # add memcache_client here
```

end